# await in for loop of TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript and this is the first time for me dealing with `async` and `await`. I have an `express` endpoint which is not async. Inside I have a for-loop that seems to require await. What would be the common way in TypeScript to iterate over this loop?

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    const resultIterator = client.query(
        'SELECT username FROM users;'
    );

    for await (const row of resultIterator) { <--- await illegal here
        // 'Hello world!'
    }
});
```

Comment: You can await on the `client.query` itself like `const resultIterator = await client.query(
        'SELECT username FROM users;' );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.get("/", async function (req, res) {
```

Express endpoints don't care whether they are async or not. You can always make them async.

You need the async keyword for await to work.

Comment: It's worth noting that express considers that the endpoint can return a Promise and that this is one effect of applying the `async` modiifer. Plenty of APIs will accept a Promise returning function and the result will be broken. For example, `Array.protoype.forEach` "doesn't care", which is precisely the problem with passing it such a a function

Comment: @AluanHaddad Express does not have any code for handling the promise returned by async. It is effectively discarded.